# How can I get activity, running and returning Location object, while being called from normal java class

Tags: java, android

I want to get location (latitude & longitude) of my device. My problem is that I want activity to be called from a normal java class which does not have context in it. Examples I have found work other way around.
I'm aware that I need to use startActivityForResult if I want something returned from activity but how can I start it without context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use application context

```
public class AppSingleton extends Application {

public static AppSingleton appSingleton;

public AppSingleton() {}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appSingleton = this;

}

public static AppSingleton getContext() {
    return sapronApplication;
}}
```

So user this  AppSingleton.getContext() to provide app context.

**EDIT**
Don't forget to add this line in manifest.xml in  section like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppSingleton"
    ...
```

Comment: What does SapronApplication stands for? Is it the activity I'm calling to get the location?

Comment: changed my code. No its just singleton class which will provide app context so you can use context dependency class anywhere in your app

Comment: Android studio does not recognize the sapronApplication.

Can you visit my new question and answer according to it?
As I have forgotten to mention that this code is part of Application with already mainActivity in it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559431/how-can-i-start-activity-and-retrieve-location-from-it-in-normal-java-class

Comment: look at the  new code you should change it to AppSingleton

Comment: It still does not recognize sapronApplication. Were exactly in Manifest should I call it? In the application brackets just open new <activity> and then add it there? I'm completely new to android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123641/discussion-between-bartek-nowak-and-anton-kazakov).